# Asp MVC 3: Modifiy Values Sent to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders, viewdata, asp.net-mvc

as far as I understand a **ModelBinder** can generate class **instances out of routedata/formdata**.

What I'm looking for is a way to **manipulate the data handed over to the view** before it is consumed by the view.

What are the possiblities? Do I miss something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I don't want to send **clear IDs** to the client but **encrypt** them (at least in **edit** cases). As it happens very often I want this step as much as possible automated.
I look for something like a ModelBinder or a Attribute to attach to a method/viewmodel/...

Example:
GET

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var vm = new EditArticleViewModel();

    ToViewModel(repository.Get<Article>(id), vm);

    return View(vm); // id is something like 5 and should be encryped before being used by the view
}
```

View

```
@model EditArticleViewModel

<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id) <!-- x.Id should be encrypted, not just "5" -->
    ...
</div>
```

Lg
warappa

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What do you want to manipulate? Ideally provide an example. What you send to a view is a view model so you can put whatever values you want in the properties of this view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something with an action filter:

```
public class EncryptIDAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var vm = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as EditArticleViewModel;

        if(vm != null)
        {
            vm.ID = SomeMethodToEncrypt(vm.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

and apply it to any relevent actions:

```
[EncryptID]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var vm = new EditArticleViewModel();

    ToViewModel(repository.Get<Article>(id), vm);

    return View(vm);
}
```

When the page is then posted you can use a model binder to decrypt the id.

If you then wanted to apply this across multiple view models you could look at creating a custom data annotation which flags a property to be encrypted. In your action filter you can then look for any properties with this data annotation and encrypt them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's the way to go! First tests seem OK, but there is one gotcha: if you're using Html.XXXFor(x => x.ID) and use the default routing then the property ID get ALWAYS picked from the routevalues. So first changing routevalue ID to Identifier makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom `HiddenFor` helper method that will automatically encrypt the value:

```
public static class HiddenExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForEncrypted<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(ex, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(ex);
        var value = metadata.Model;
        var encryptedValue = SomeFunctionToEncrypt(value);
        return htmlHelper.Hidden(name, encryptedValue);
    }
}
```

As an alternative you could use the [Html.Serialize](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx) helper in the MVCFutures assembly that does this under the covers.

So basically you will write in your view:

```
@Html.Serialize("id", Model.Id, SerializationMode.Encrypted)
```

and in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Deserialize(SerializationMode.Encrypted)]int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but it's still kinda manual (use the right extension method). If you would use the id in ActionLinks then you get the problem there again. I favour a solution which kicks in "silently" - no special method calls; "plug-n-play" ;)

Comment: @Warappa, unfortunately there is no magic :-) The model binder you are talking about is just used for binding request values. This could be used to decrypt on the server side. But sending an encrypted value could be done through custom helpers.

Comment: BTW thanks for mentioning Html.Serialize - I didn't know that one.

Comment: @Warappa, yeah, that's a very useful helper. It uses classic WebForms ViewState :-) I am using it sometimes when I need to persist some models across multiple actions (for example in multistep wizards). It also happens to allow encrypting the values stored in those hidden fields. But in the case of an ActionLink it won't be helpful for you.