# MVC 3 Model Binding without Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, key, model-binding

I have a question about ASP.NET MVC3 model binding. If I have a class I'm trying to use as a model, but I don't want the key put on the page, the model doesn't bind on a POST. Here is an example:

```
//Data Model
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    public string MyKey {get;set;} //Perhaps this is an ssn that I don't want on the form.
    public string MyValueToGet {get;set;} //This is the value I want the user to enter.
}

//Conroller code.
public ViewResult Index()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel{ MyKey = "SecretInfo", MyValueToGet = "" };
    return View(new model);
}
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
{
    repository.SaveChanges(model)
}

//View code.
@using(Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Enter a value: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyValueToGet)
    <input type="submit" value="Salve" />
}
```

So my problem is that model is null when the Edit method is called upon form submission. I can fix this by putting MyKey somewhere on the page (perhaps as a hidden field), but that is unacceptable if it is some sort of sensitive data. Is there a way to solve this problem? I am new to MVC, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: Store the SecretInfo in `Session` or `TempData` (which is form of session and persists upon next web request)

Comment: Will the default model binder pick up on the fact that the key is located in the Session or TempData? I thought the default model binder only checked the Form, RoutData.Values, QueryString and Rquest.Files.

Comment: The intent of a view model is to build a view, so if you don't want an info to be in the view, you should definitely store it elsewhere.

Comment: You might be able to make a custom model binder that retrieves the key from `Session`

Comment: The problem is I'm using Entity Framework to update my database, and it requires the key to do it. So how can I give all the fields that need to be editable to the view without also giving it the key value while still allowing Entity Framework to update the database?

Comment: Luke, I have considered that option, and I think it might work. I just thought there might be a way to do it with the default model binder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another unique but otherwise meaningless identifier like an (auto increment int) and use that to bind.

in other words modify your model to something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string MyKey {get;set;} //Now this can be sensitive, it doesn't matter because you no longer rely on it.
    public string MyValueToGet {get;set;} //This is the value I want the user to enter.
}
```

**EDIT**

I believe your best choice would be to change the MyModel object, as it's design is flawed.  The primary key in the majority of cases (and I think this is one of them) should be a simple auto incrementing integer, meaningless apart from it's role as the table's key.

While Luke's suggestion to use Session is a viable option and a solution that would work, I would personally do something similar to what I'll explain here, as it would seem to me to be more of the 'mvc way' of doing things.

**Data model:**
Either change your current model to something like what I suggest above, or, if that is not feasible for whatever reason (breaking dependancies or FK relationships), create a new table that can be used as a join, or proxy, if you will:

```
public class Proxy
{
    public int ProxyId {get;set;}
    public MyModel MyModel {get; set;}
}
```

Obviously, you'd have to do some work to populate this table, but you would then be able to use it to fetch records from `MyModel` without accessing the `MyKey` property directly.

It's not considered good practice to use your data models directly in your views, so you want to create a **view model** as well

```
public class MyModelViewModel
{
    public int ModelId {get; set;}
    public string ModelValueToGet {get; set;}
}
```

Notice we don't even need the key containing sensitive data in the view model.

Then type your **view** to the viewModel, not the data model, and include a hidden field for the ModelId

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Enter a value: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelValueToGet)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelId)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Now in your **controller** you have your get method

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    //fetch the users record from the database 
    //if you're using the Proxy table, you'll want to write a LINQ query here
    //instantiate a viewModel and populate it's properties using the fetched record
    //remember, the viewModel.ModelId should be set to MyModel.ID or Proxy.ProxyId 
    //render the view
}
```

And the post method

```
public ViewResult Edit (MyModelViewModel viewModel)
{
    //fetch the users record from the database using viewModel.ModelId
    //If you're using the proxy table, you'll need to use that LINQ query again here
    //update the record you fetched with the new data the user just entered
    //you have complete control here of what gets updated and what stays the same
    //pass the updated record to the repository to save the changes.
    //redirect the user to be on their merry way
}
```

I think that's about as well as I can lay it out.  Hope it makes sense.

Comment: So when I pass my model to my repository to update my database, how will it know to use the real key instead of the meaningless identifier?

Comment: It won't have to use the real key if the new identifier is unique;)

Comment: But there is no corresponding value in the database for the unique identifier. How will Entity Framework know which row to update?

Comment: So if I tried to tie my model to Entity Framework, would it give me an error saying that "ID" doesn't exist in the table?

Comment: Ok, I see. So you're saying I could perhaps use an Identity Key on the table. That definitely sounds like a viable solution, as does Luke's suggestion of using a custom model binder. I'll give them a shot.

Comment: One other question relating to this. Won't the sensitive data be null when my form is given back to me as a model since I didn't put it on the page some where? How do I prevent the SaveChanges() call in my repository from overwriting my sensitive data with null?

Comment: @RalpghCholo Just edited my answer with the detailed approach I would take.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to encrypt the id before sending it to the client.  Check this post for more information on how to accomplish this.
[Asp MVC 3: Modifiy Values Sent to View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909352/asp-mvc-3-modifiy-values-sent-to-view)